# Rotate $y=e^{-x^2}$ about the y-axis to find the volume.

Tags: calculus

[image]

Since we are rotating around the y-axis, my intuition is that I need to change my original function in terms of y instead of $x$. So to change $y=e^{-x^2}$, I should end with $x=(-ln(y))^{(1/2)}$. At first I thought this could cause a problem, but then I realized that my original function only has y values going form $0$ to $1$, so I thought I should be okay. Then to find volume, I should do the $\pi(Int[0,1])((-ln(y))^{(1/2)})^2 dy$. Which just ends up being $-\pi(Int[0,1])(ln(y))dy$. However, you cannot evaluate the integral of $ln(y)$ from 0 to 1 because there ends up being a part that is undefined. Therefore, I feel that I must have done something wrong along the way. I am teaching a calculus recitation but it has been a few years since I've dealt with these types of problems. I know that this may be solved using the shell method, however, the class requires specifically that they use the disk method for this problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do indeed want 
$$\int_0^1 -\pi \ln y\,dy.\tag{1}$$
The logarithm blows up as $y$ approaches $0$ from the right, so we want to find (if it exists)
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^1-\pi\ln y\,dy.\tag{2}$$
An antiderivative of $\ln y$ is $y\ln y-y$ (integration by parts). The integral (2) is therefore equal to 
$$-\pi\left[((1)\ln 1-1)-(\epsilon\ln \epsilon-\epsilon)                       \right].$$ 
Finally, take the limit as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ from the right. We need to know that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \epsilon\ln \epsilon=0$. This can be proved using L'Hospital's Rule, or in various other ways.

Comment: Using what you have given me, I get a result of pi. However, this does not match the answer given by @Adriano below, so maybe you could explain what hte issue is here?

Comment: The main difference is that I think the upper limit in the integral should be $1$, not $e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you get the full solid from just rotating the curve $e^{-x^2}$, $0\le x<\infty$ about the $x$-axis.

You can now find the volume using the shell method:

$V=\int_0^\infty 2\pi xe^{-x^2}dx$.  This integral can be done reasonably routinely, perhaps by a $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the highest part the curve is $(0, e^{-1})$, so our desired volume is:
$$
-\pi\lim_{k \to 0^+}\int_k^{1/e} \ln y \, dy
= -\pi\lim_{k \to 0^+}\left[y\ln y - y \right]_k^{1/e}
= \frac{2\pi}{e}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$$ Notice that our function is even, so $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$$ Next, consider $$2\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dy$$ Convince yourself that $$2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dy$$ which means that $$I^2 = \left(2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right) \left(2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right) \\ =\left(2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right) \left(2\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dd\right) \\ =4\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy $$ where we are guaranteed equality in the last line because $I$ is always positive. Lastly, we will now switch to polar coordinates. We have $x^2+y^2=r^2$ with $dxdy = rd\theta dr$ and our integral transforms to $$=4\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-r^2}rd\theta dr$$ At this point the integral can be completed via a simple $u$-sub. I recommend integrating with respect to $\theta$ first, and using symmetry properties the integral will only require one improper integration instead of two.

You should get a volume of $\pi$ at the end.

Comment: I understand what you have done, but the class I am instructing has not yet gone over anything involving polar coordinates or double integrals, so I believe there should be a way to do it without using those things

Comment: The above is a calculation of the area under the curve, not the volume of the solid of revolution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for pointing that out: Post has been edited to reflect volume.